# Screenshot area to clipboard (Control + Command + Shift + 4) doesn't work

Tags: mac, screen-capture, copy-paste

According to the [Mac support docs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361), I should be able to use `Command-Shift-Control-4` to take an area screenshot to the clipboard.

This doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?  Whether I use an external keyboard or not it doesn't work.

`Command-Shift-4` works just fine.  I'm on 10.11.6

Comment: Are you certain that where you're pasting it can accept it, & that you performed no other clipboard action in between? It's not something I normally use, but tested to Photoshop just fine. Also confirmed copying some text afterwards will kill the image in the buffer

Comment: Yes, if I copy an image from the browser it works just fine.

Also, the crosshairs never change as they do with `Command-Shift-4`.

Comment: hmm... does cmd/shift/ctrl/3 work to grab the entire screen? I'm thinking key conflict [but idk where]

Comment: No, that doesn't work either, although `Command-Shift-3` works fine.

Comment: Checked they're enabled in sys prefs/Keyboard/shortcuts/screen shots? [You can tell I'm running out of ideas ;)

Comment: Ah!  Thank you!  New to mac.  I didn't see what it was, but I hit "Restore Defaults" and that fixed it.

Comment: for the sake of completeness, let me throw some of that into an answer... just in case anyone Googles it in future...

Answer (score 4):

Things to check...

- The receiving app can accept the format, .png by default.
- The buffer hasn't been replaced with other content, text etc.
- If  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>  would work to capture the entire screen to clipboard.
- That the key commands are on & set to defaults in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Screen Shots & also that resetting to defaults doesn't generate an orange warning triangle that another shortcut is using the same key command.

Comment: Brilliant thank you! Keyboard in system prefs worked for me!

Comment: still no luck for me

Comment: the only app I can paste a screenshot into is discord

Answer (score 3):

If it’s a MacBook Pro with touchbar make sure the camera icon is not in the touchbar

Comment: What is the significance of the camera icon here, and how can one make it disappear?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a MacBook Pro with touchbar, look at the touchbar.
You should see three options:

- Selected Portion
- Window
- Entire Screen

Select the first option and that will start being your new default.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it turned out be Quicksilver and specifically the '**clipboard plugin**' in Quicksilver that was causing the problem for some reason.

As soon as I disabled the shortcut to paste from the clipboard for <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd> (and <kbd>3</kbd>), then it started working again!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a Mac screenshot bug with [finder relaunch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZPic.png); you can try that, it might work for your case.