# Command-Control-Shift-4 doesn't work. How to capture portion of screen to clipboard?

Tags: catalina, screen-capture

How to capture

1. portion of screen
2. to clipboard

Command-Control-Shift-4 doesn't work (cross cursor doesn't appear). Command-Shift-4 shows cross cursor but captures not into clipboard. Command-Control-Shift-3 captures to clipboard, but entire screen, not portion.

Comment: Please have a look at: [Take a screenshot on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361)

Comment: I just tried `Command-Control-Shift-4` and .. it worked. Is it enabled in the Screenshot keyboard shortcut settings?

Comment: @Dims a "moderator" deleted the answer where I posted a screenshot that shows that `Command-Control-Shift-4` is a valid, built-in keyboard shortcut that needs to be enabled. Can you verify your Screenshot shortcuts at `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Screenshots` ? On Big Sur 11.4 the 4th setting is `Copy picture .... to the clipboard ⌃⇧⌘4`

Comment: [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253796/screenshot-area-to-clipboard-control-command-shift-4-doesnt-work) is essentially a duplicate of your question - except the answers didn't get deleted. Try clicking `Restore Defaults` in the keyboard settings. Check for programs that may me using the same keyboard combination. Try pasting in different applications - not all applications allow image pasting. The StackExchange/SO editor allows pasting images directly into the image box.

Comment: The answers that talk about the touchbar may appear to be weird *but* displaying an action in the touchbar may be disabling the keyboard shortcut. In my case I display function keys permanently

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for finding the duplicate. Please flag/propose to close in such cases

Comment: @nohillside I think I'll simply abandon apple.stackexchange.com instead. The hostility I've found in just a couple of days is astounding, and I've been a moderator of a big forum with some really obnoxious users for 16 years. As for marking as duplicate, I can't because when moderators delete answers gratuitously, it's impossible to get rep.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Every user can flag a question, independent of reputation. Also, if you think moderators are handling posts wrongly please bring it up on Meta so the whole community can join the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the built-in "Screenshot" app to select things to take a screenshot of.

I use cmd-shift-4. Without the control key.

Otherwise, I'd suggest checking your keyboard shortcut settings and just make sure that nothing else is using your command.

Comment: The OP is asking about a built-in  Screenshot shortcut.

Comment: cmd-shift-4 is a built-in shortcut to snapshot a rectangle. cnd-shift-3 snapshots the whole screen - this is what I usually do and then crop it in preview.

Answer (score 2):

It worked on my machine (Big Sur 11.4). I didn't even know this shortcut existed until I saw this question. Is the shortcut enabled in Keyboard settings? The settings screenshot below was created using Command-Control-Shift-4 and pasting directly into SO's Image box

[image: Keyboard shortcut, screenshot settings showing Control+Shift+Command+4]